# write NFC Tag in Android

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare, ndef

I'm working on an App for android you write NFC tags.
Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
NfcAdapter adapter;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
boolean writeMode;
Tag myTag;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Definimos el layout a usar
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;
    //Los elementos que vamos a usar en el layout
    Button btnWrite = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    //setOnCLickListener hará la acción que necesitamos
    btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  try{
          //Si no existe tag al que escribir, mostramos un mensaje de que no existe.
          if(myTag == null){
              Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_notag), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }else{
              //Llamamos al método write que definimos más adelante donde le pasamos por
              //parámetro el tag que hemos detectado y el mensaje a escribir.
              write(message.getText().toString(), myTag);
              Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.ok_write), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
   }catch(IOException e){
       Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_write),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       e.printStackTrace();
   }catch(FormatException e){
       Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_write), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

});

```
    adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[]{tagDetected};
}
//El método write es el más importante, será el que se encargue de crear el mensaje 
//y escribirlo en nuestro tag.
private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException{
  //Creamos un array de elementos NdefRecord. Este Objeto representa un registro del mensaje NDEF   
  //Para crear el objeto NdefRecord usamos el método createRecord(String s)
  NdefRecord[] records = {createRecord(text)};
  //NdefMessage encapsula un mensaje Ndef(NFC Data Exchange Format). Estos mensajes están 
  //compuestos por varios registros encapsulados por la clase NdefRecord  
  NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
  //Obtenemos una instancia de Ndef del Tag
  Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
  ndef.connect();
  ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
  ndef.close();
}
//Método createRecord será el que nos codifique el mensaje para crear un NdefRecord
private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String lang = "us";
    byte[] textBytes = text.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int langLength = langBytes.length;
    int textLength = textBytes.length;
    byte[] payLoad = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

    payLoad[0] = (byte) langLength;

    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payLoad, 1, langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payLoad, 1+langLength, textLength);

    NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payLoad);

    return recordNFC;

}
//en onnewIntent manejamos el intent para encontrar el Tag
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.ok_detected) + myTag.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    WriteModeOff();
}
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    WriteModeOn();
}

private void WriteModeOn(){
    writeMode = true;
    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
}

private void WriteModeOff(){
    writeMode = false;
    adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
```

}

The Tag is detected perfectly, but if I try to write in it gives me the following error:

```
java.io.IOException
at android.nfc.tech.Ndef.writeNdefMessage(Ndef.java:313)
at com.example.nfc_prueba.MainActivity.write(MainActivity.java:91)
at com.example.nfc_prueba.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:76)
```

The Tag type is:
Mifare Classic 1K

I don´t know why doesn´t write in it. Any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you declared android.permission.NFC at manifest?

Comment: You should reconsider your design approach: Currently you retrieve a handle to the tag upon tag detection and later (upon clicking somewhere), you try to write data to the tag. NFC, however, is intended for very short interactions. Thus, your user should first indicate that uon the next tap of a tag some data should be written, then the app should wait for the user tapping the tag (foreground dispatch) and then, immediately upon receiving the tag detection intent, the data should be written to the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much for your help. 
I finally found the reason why not write data to the tag. I had to reformat the card to NDEF with This function:

```
NdefFormatable formatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);

    if (formatable != null) {
      try {
        formatable.connect();

        try {
          formatable.format(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          // let the user know the tag refused to format
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        // let the user know the tag refused to connect
      }
      finally {
        formatable.close();
      }
    }
    else {
      // let the user know the tag cannot be formatted
    }
```

thank you very much again!

Regards.